# Non-required lookup + lookup formula WHERE condition = weird results?

Tags: soql, formula, lookup

Lets assume sObject_A with a formula field that calculates some positive number based on record fields. If the number cannot be calculated due to lack of data, the number is set to `-1`.

sObject_B has non-required lookup to sObject_A.

Now i want to query all sObject_B records where there is no calculating error in the formula field. So naturally i go for:
`SELECT Id FROM sObject_B WHERE sObject_A__r.formula__c != -1`
but i don't get any records where sObject_A__c lookup is empty.

If I change the condition to `sObject_A__r.formula__c = -1` the records with empty lookup are also not returned (naturally).

So now there is situation where CONDITION OR NOT(CONDITION) doest not cover all the records. As if instead of record not existing in lookup, there is a phantom record that has formulas calculated when `!=` is used.

The workaround is instead of returning `-1` for calculating error, use `IF( ISBLANK(Id), -2, -1 )`. Now the aforementioned condition works for both, empty lookup or lookup record having a calculating error.

I guess the question is: is this expected behaviour? If so, where can I find documentation, that says so?

Comment: Can you try:

SELECT Id FROM sObject_B WHERE sObject_A__c = null OR sObject_A__r.formula__c != -1

This should fetch all the sObject_B record, with empty lookups and also the one with lookup with the formula field of the child is not = -1

Comment: Hi, this is what I ended up doing.